# SQL 2014 Always On Availability Groups - Read Replica

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups

I'm not familiar with Always On Availability Groups, but our company is using it to provide a read-only replica for our main production database so that certain users can report against it and generate ad-hoc queries.

Since this is read-only, I know that no modifications can be made to this database. However, I was wondering if it's ever necessary to rebuild indexes or regenerate statistics on a read replica like this? Or, does this happen automatically when the the source database has indexes rebuilt or statistics regenerated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't need to rebuild indexes or update statistics. You can't do any writes to a readable replica at all.

Comment: You are correct about stats update is not possible, but one must also note that statistics on secondary replica can be stale or outdated for *queries running* on read only databases in that case information mentioned in [This Blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2011/12/22/alwayson-making-latest-statistics-available-on-readable-secondary-read-only-database-and-database-snapshot/) can help

Comment: This being the case, how do statistics get updated on a read replica? Hmm.. according to the article Shanky provided, I guess you can't. However, that article was from almost 6 years ago.

Comment: Stats get updated the same way data does - from the primary.